# Hyperref package issue with cite border

Tags: hyperref, citing

I am trying to get the hyperref package to display the default green boxes around the citation but when typesetted, there is no such formatting. Here is the preamble that I have currently in my TeX file:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[
 % authoryear,
round, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\cite{foo}

\begin{thebibliography}{foo}
\bibitem{foo} Foo.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

I have tried adding the following at ***different*** times to try to add the cite borders to no avail:

```
\usepackage[citebordercolor=green]{hyperref}
\usepackage[citebordercolor=red]{hyperref}
\usepackage[pdfborder=0 0 1]{hyperref}
```

I'm not sure if there is a conflict between packages in the existing preamble above but I have tried all suggestions I have came across in this forum and others but have not yet been successful. Can you offer any suggestions?

(P.S. I am compiling with XeLaTeX)

Comment: I get green borders around citation links with this preamble. Make a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Can you send me the tex file that you have run successfully with green borders?

Comment: I have put it in the question. Please optimize the example: Remove packages that are not needed to reproduce the problem and add the necessary code of your real TeX file to show the problem.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Unless we can ascertain that the other packages or not preventing the typesetting of the green borders, I think they should remain in the question.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Find the simplified MWE. This does not solve my issue when complied, I'm afraid.

Comment: Do you get link borders at all (e.g. `\ref`, `\url`)? Have you tried a different PDF viewer? What happens, if you compile with `pdflatex` instead of `xelatex`?

Comment: I have tried three different PDF viewers, complied with pdflatex and also I have the same issue with link borders I'm afraid.

Comment: With the example of the question or your real world document? Any errors/warnings in the `.log` file?

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I've notice that using \hypersetup{colorlink=true}

The citation words turn green and links turn a red/pink.

Comment: Yes, that is the purpose of option `colorlinks`.

Comment: I understand that but I thought it was odd that this option works but many others do not in this case.

Comment: Which options do not work? Are there warnings of `hyperref`? (Not all options can be given at all places.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something has fixed after all !! But ..

When compiling the above code using xelatex I get the green boxes, in the TexStudio pdf viewer BUT NOT in SUMATRA!

Acrobat and other readers were fine.

For reference I include is my current configuration.

The green boxes can be seen with the same original code

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex


\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[
 % authoryear,
round, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\cite{foo}

\begin{thebibliography}{foo}
\bibitem{foo} Foo.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999992 (MiKTeX 20.7) (preloaded format=xelatex 2020.10.10)  26 OCT 2020 18:49
entering extended mode
**"./green boxes xelatex.tex"
("green boxes xelatex.tex"
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5

[image: output]

Related to

[no border around hyperlinks with hyperref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/210640/no-border-around-hyperlinks-with-hyperref/210777#210777)