# no border around hyperlinks with hyperref

Tags: hyperref, mactex, texshop, links

MacTEX-2014, TeXShop 3.36.1 on Mac OS 10.9.5 -- when using hyperref I do not see the colored border that should appear around the hyperlinks in the pdf.

for example, when compiled with pdflatex, the code below should produce a pdf with a green border around the link on the right of "abc", but it does not. Any idea how to check where the problem is?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=false,pdfborder=0 0 1,citebordercolor={0 1 0}}
\begin{document}

abc \cite{123}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{123} efg
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

this is the list of files from the generated .log

> *File List*
>   article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
>   size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
>   hyperref.sty    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hypertext links for LaTeX
>   hobsub-hyperref.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
>   hobsub-generic.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
>     hobsub.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Construct package bundles (HO)
>   infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
>    ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
>   ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
>     ifvtex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.5 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
>    intcalc.sty    2007/09/27 v1.1 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
>      ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
>   etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
>   kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
>   kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
>   pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
>   pdfescape.sty    2011/11/25 v1.13 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
>   bigintcalc.sty    2012/04/08 v1.3 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
>     bitset.sty    2011/01/30 v1.1 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
>   uniquecounter.sty    2011/01/30 v1.2 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
>   letltxmacro.sty    2010/09/02 v1.4 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
>    hopatch.sty    2012/05/28 v1.2 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
>   xcolor-patch.sty    2011/01/30 xcolor patch
>   atveryend.sty    2011/06/30 v1.8 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
>   atbegshi.sty    2011/10/05 v1.16 At begin shipout hook (HO)
>   refcount.sty    2011/10/16 v3.4 Data extraction from label references (HO)
>    hycolor.sty    2011/01/30 v1.7 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
>     keyval.sty    2014/05/08 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
>    ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
>    auxhook.sty    2011/03/04 v1.3 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
>   kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
>     pd1enc.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
>   hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
>        url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
>    hpdftex.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
>   rerunfilecheck.sty    2011/04/15 v1.7 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
>    nameref.sty    2012/10/27 v2.43 Cross-referencing by name of section
>   gettitlestring.sty    2010/12/03 v1.4 Cleanup title references (HO)

Comment: Maybe it is a problem with the display or the settings of `ocg`? IIRC the boxes are set using `ocg` so that they don't get printed.

Comment: what is ocg? how can check the settings of ocg?

Comment: Exactly how do you see that it does not add a green border? Which previewer?

Comment: `ocg` (Optional Content Groups) is a feature of pdf that isn't supported perfectly by all viewers. Have you tried another viewer?

Comment: with Texshop or with mac Preview same result (I did not have this problem with older version of MacTEX, TeXShop and osx)

Comment: I have just checked the pdf that I have generated from the code above on a pc windows 8.1 with AcrobatReader and with FoxitReader: same problem, no border ... it does not seem a problem of visualization

Comment: There is another question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199895/hyperref-boxes-around-links-are-missing-in-texshop which report the same problem... is there anyone else that can reproduce this behavior with MacTEX-2014 and Texshop 3.36?

Comment: what is MWE?...

Comment: where should I add \listfiles?

Comment: Results on my machine: Mactex 2013, OSX mavericks. In Preview, Skim and Texshop previewer there is no border. However, in Texstudio previewer I see the green border. Funny enough, if I open the produced pdf in Firefox, I can see the border as well.

Comment: Related Question: [Hyphenate URLs in paragraphs while maintaining an underline link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/505448/4301).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is *not* a problem with TeX. Displaying the box is up to the PDF viewer. So, the above code (run on Mac OS 10.9.5) with TeXShop 3.45.1 is shown as follows:

1. TeXShop 3.45.1 Viewer: no box

   [image]
2. Acrobat 11.0.9 : box

   [image]
3. Mac Preview (Mac OS 10.9.5): no box

   [image]
4. Firefox 33.0.2 (Mac OS 10.9.5): box

   [image]
5. Chrome and Safari (Mac OS 10.9.5): no box

Answer (score 5):

To simply resolve this problem put this in your document
after the "\usepackage"es

```
\hypersetup{pdfborder = {0 0 0}}
```

Comment: You are trying to solve a problem that only exists in the viewer...

Comment: You are correct but that is a problem and not supposed to be like this.

Comment: this answer will fix it no matter where you are looking at it.

Comment: \hypersetup{pdfborder = {0 0 0}} does not give a border for me; \hypersetup{pdfborder = {1 1 1}} does give a red border for me.