# Hyphenate URLs in paragraphs while maintaining an underline link

Tags: hyperref, hyphenation, urls, links

**Problem:**

I wish to break or hyphenate links in paragraphs while maintaining an underline link.

**Minimal Working Example (MWE):**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[OT6,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,urlcolor=black}

\makeatletter
\DeclareUrlCommand\ULurl@@{%
  \def\UrlFont{\color{black}}%
  \def\UrlLeft{\uline\bgroup}%
  \def\UrlRight{\egroup}}
\def\ULurl@#1{\hyper@linkurl{\ULurl@@{#1}}{#1}}
\DeclareRobustCommand*\ULurl{\hyper@normalise\ULurl@}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\noindent Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque elit massa, volutpat a mattis vel, dictum dapibus sapien. Ut mollis neque quis sapien convallis accumsan. Proin vel odio sit amet neque euismod ultrices. Sed ut dolor quis nunc convallis eleifend vel eget mauris. Nulla eget viverra felis, sit amet vehicula lacus. Praesent at ex id justo rutrum egestas. \ULurl{http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/}. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque elit massa, volutpat a mattis vel, dictum dapibus sapien from \ULurl{https://creativecommons.org/about/downloads/}. 
\end{document}
```

**Outcome:**

[image]

**Desired outcome:**

To break/hypenate links so that they may not extend beyond the width of text.

Comment: Off-topic: if you place your examples code between `\begin{sloppypar}` and `\end{sloppypar}` seems nice to me... But of course no hyphenation happens on the underlined text. On-topic: you should add in the title that the hyperlink's text should be underlined. Makes much difference.

Comment: @koleygr Adjusted, thanks for input

Answer (score 2):

Just load the `xurl` package immediately before `hyperref` and use the basic `\url` macro.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[OT6,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{xurl}  % <-- new
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,urlcolor=black}


\begin{document}
\noindent 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque elit massa, volutpat a mattis vel, dictum dapibus sapien. Ut mollis neque quis sapien convallis accumsan. Proin vel odio sit amet neque euismod ultrices. Sed ut dolor quis nunc convallis eleifend vel eget mauris. Nulla eget viverra felis, sit amet vehicula lacus. Praesent at ex id justo rutrum egestas. \url{http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/}. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque elit massa, volutpat a mattis vel, dictum dapibus sapien from \url{https://creativecommons.org/about/downloads/}. 
\end{document}
```

Comment: But this doesn't give un underlined link.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - I was assuming that the OP had inserted the instruction `\hypersetup{colorlinks,urlcolor=black}` for a reason. Maybe I assumed too much.

Comment: well the OP used \uline in the command and asks about an "underline link".

Answer (score 2):

You could set the pdfborderstyle to underline:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[OT6,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
 urlbordercolor=black,
 pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W 1}
 }

\begin{document}

\noindent Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque elit massa, volutpat a mattis vel, dictum dapibus sapien. Ut mollis neque quis sapien convallis accumsan. Proin vel odio sit amet neque euismod ultrices. Sed ut dolor quis nunc convallis eleifend vel eget mauris. Nulla eget viverra felis, sit amet vehicula lacus. Praesent at ex id justo rutrum egestas. \url{http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/}. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque elit massa, volutpat a mattis vel, dictum dapibus sapien from \url{https://creativecommons.org/about/downloads/}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have adopted your approach but it does not produce any underline in Texpad.

Comment: +1 for producing a hyperlink with an underline. :-)

Comment: how such a border is shown depends on the pdfviewer.