# How to underline a URL hyperlink in Latex?

Tags: hyperref, underline

How to make a underline for my URL, 
I tried `\underline` but is not useful, it make the text over the pages.

[image: hyperref]

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[OT6,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
 urlbordercolor=black,
 pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W 1}
 }

\begin{document}

The URL is \url{http://testing.com}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/505455/2388

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, i had tried, but it seemed not working. I edited my question.

Comment: As mentioned in a comment below my answer it depends on the pdf viewer if the border is correctly rendered. On windows in adobe reader and sumatra it works fine.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer. Sorry, didnt understand your meaning. I am using overleaf and windows

Comment: As UlrikeFischer said, this is dependent on the pdf viewer. Thus, is this a duplicate of [No border around hyperlinks with hyperref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/210640/4301)?