# Unwanted boxes around words

Tags: packages, glossaries, links

I'm using the following packages

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[toc, acronym]{glossaries}

when I use commands such as \gls{}, \acrshort{}, \ref{}... the pdf file generated by LaTeX contains ugly boxes around words and numbers:
[image]

is it possible to get rid of such boxes?

Comment: Hi, welcome. These are made by the `hyperref` package I believe, and indicate that the cross references are clickable. `\hypersetup{hidelinks}` to remove them, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/823/remove-ugly-borders-around-clickable-cross-references-and-hyperlinks

Comment: Thanks, problem solved

Comment: Be aware that the display of the boxes is viewer dependent: [no border around hyperlinks with hyperref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/210640/4301).